# How to repeat a character multiple times as a MATLAB array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat, character-arrays

Given a single string value in a MATLAB character array:

```
['12 N']
```

How can I repeat this value X times in a new character array?

For example:

X = 5

```
['12 N'; '12 N'; '12 N'; '12 N'; '12 N']
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function:

```
A = ['12 N'];
X = 5
Output = repmat(A, X, 1);
```

will result in a character array.

Depending on your end usage, you may want to consider using a cell array of strings instead:

```
Output = repmat({A},X,1);
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me as I was typing out the answer!

Comment: The last line is incorrect: `repmat({A},X,1);` creates a cell array of char arrays, not strings. (Edit: I realize that when this answer was posted, Matlab had not introduced the `string` class yet, so the words "strings" were sometimes used to refer to char arrays)

Answer (score 3):

`repmat` is the obvious way to go, but just for the heck of it you could use `kron`:

```
A = ['12 N'];
X = 5
B = char(kron(A,ones(X,1)))
```

Silly, yes...